# set "security.mixed_content.block_active_content" to false programmatically

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I wanted to set the `security.mixed_content.block_active_content` attribute in Firefox to `false` for some of the functionality in our application to work.

Higher versions of FF had that attribute set to `true` by default.

Can any one please help how to do this programmatically by using java/javascript.
If possible please share the code. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: You cannot do this programmatically. It's an option within the user-level configuration of Firefox which JS (nor any other script) has access to. If you need this setting changed, you will have to do it yourself manually, or give your user instructions on how to change it. Or better yet, fix the issue by serving all content from HTTPS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: yeah, Thank you so much for information @RoryMcCrossan